# SQL group by to concatenate text

Tags: sql, string, netezza

Never ran into this before.  I'd like to do it in SQL, but I can in Excel as a fall-back... It's a relatively small set of data.

Suppose I have the following data:

```
foo | val
----+-----
 A  | red
 A  | blue
 B  | up
 B  | down
```

...and I want the result...

```
foo | agg
----+---------
 A  | red,blue
 B  | up,down
```

So if I could invent my own aggregate functions, it would be:

```
select foo
      ,concat(val,',') as agg
from mytable
group by 1
```

Does anything like this exist?  Specifically I'm on Netezza.

Thanks!

Comment: Which RDBMS is this? SQL Server?

Comment: Nope, this is Netezza.

Comment: https://www-304.ibm.com/connections/forums/html/topic?id=a2402d13-1fdc-4e65-b0ad-adbedbe2c9e1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the thread https://www-304.ibm.com/connections/forums/html/topic?id=a2402d13-1fdc-4e65-b0ad-adbedbe2c9e1
May be it will be of your help. But for single pass query, you have to be sure for possible maximum number of repetition. Or you can have a multi pass query